# SQL statement return matching records from join and null records from join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a db with records like the following structure in the table;

```
 id,msg,date,fid 
 19 ,"start","2012-02",NULL
 20 ,"end","2012-03",19
 21 , "start",2012-04,NULL
```

I have and entire db set up like this where the fid in some cases matches the id of another record. Id like to return all records that have matching start and end dates and just the start date if it doesn't have a corresponding end date fid like below:

```
19 ,"start","2012-02","end","2012-03"
21 , "start,"2012-04,"",NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
select t.fid, t.date as start_date, tf.date as end_date
from t left join
     t tf
     on tf.id = t.fid
where t.msg = 'start'
```

This assumes that there are only two types of records and `fid` is always non-`NULL` for `'end'` records.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a LEFT OUTER JOIN to your table. You can use an alias to refer to each instance:

```
SELECT startdt.id, startdt.msg, startdt.date, enddt.msg, enddt.date
FROM yourtable as startdt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable as enddt
        ON startdt.fid = enddt.id
        AND enddt.msg = 'end'
WHERE startdt.msg = 'start'
```

Comment: i get no records,   the sql line   ON startdt.fid = enddt.id       if switched    ' starddt.fid.id =enddt.id ' around gives me records but doesn't include start dates that don't have matching end dates  ie see record 19. i want to include records both like 19 and 21

Comment: I can't imagine how `starddt.fid.id =enddt.id` would work. That seems like nonsense. The LEFT OUTER JOIN here should do exactly what you are asking, but I feel there is some information about your table schema that you are not sharing. Something is strange here.